# literal_eval incorrectly parsing ints

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to use the `ast.literal_eval` function to parse a dictionary string into a dictionary. The issue I am having is that the function is incorrectly evaluating integers of the form `0420` as `272`. Is there a better way to do this?

**Example:**

**String:**

```
{"neurons": [80, 140, 84, 5], "epochs": 0420}
```

**Output**

```
{'epochs': 272, 'neurons': [80, 140, 84, 5]}
```

Comment: That's not incorrect parsing; in Python 2.x, [numeric literals](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#numeric-literals) starting with a zero are *octal* (in 3.x, they're a syntax error). Where is this data coming from? What did you expect instead (`"0420"`? `420`?)

Comment: That's my bad. Yes I expected to get 420 in this case. Is there a way to do this effectively?

Comment: You could parse it yourself, or pre-process the string to remove those leading zeros.